# What do you call a symmetric tridiagonal matrix with an arithmetic progression along its main diagonal?

Tags: matrices

Does anyone know how such a matrix is referred to in the literature? Ultimately my goal is to look for an analytic expression for its determinant. But because I don't know what it's called, it's been very difficult to go through the literature... Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I don't think it has a specific name.